# Fix azure service hooks trigger timeout due to New IP ranges are being added to the India geography

Tags: azure, azure-devops

azure service hooks trigger suddenly stopped working due to timeout to Jenkins service deployed on Azure VM.

```
An error occurred while sending the request.
    Unable to connect to the remote server
    A connection attempt failed because the connected party did not properly respond after a period of time, or established connection failed because connected host has failed to respond
```

Does anyone know what IPs need to be added to the firewall for this matter?

[image: Service hook]

Comment: Would you please help clarify your issue in detail? Why do you think this issue is caused by new IP ranges being added to the India geography? See the ip range of Azure DevOps service from [Allowed IP addresses and domain URLs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/organizations/security/allow-list-ip-url?view=azure-devops&tabs=IP-V6#:~:text=20.195.68.0/24-,India,-South%20India)

Comment: @ZiyangLiu-MSFT  I update the question. I updated the firewall as per your link. Noting happened. `India  South India  20.41.194.0/24`

Comment: Did you make any change to your Jenkins service or VM recently? To narrow down the issue, please try to create a new webhook and use the same Jenkins service. If the new webhook works, the issue is related to the webhook itself. If not, create a new webhook to a new Jenkins service and check if it has the same error or not.  If not, the issue may be related to your original Jenkins service.